# Work on visual studio project with 2-3 people at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, collaboration

I'm going to start working on a project with 2 friends and we're all using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I'm currently using TortoiseSVN but then it gets messy when updating removes the code i written. Is there like a live editor plugin? so like one person can work on Toolbox.cpp and then after he saves it it will sync to the other team members?

Comment: Use a better version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/); try to have each member team work mostly on a his own translation units and/or modules. Your mess is probably more a matter of work organization than of tools. I feel your question is off-topic here, since you don't show any source code, and it is too broad.

Comment: [Using Git with Visual Studio 2013 Jump Start (Microsoft Virtual Academy)](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/using-git-with-visual-studio-2013-jump-start-8306)

Comment: SVN doesn't remove any code you've written. It merges the changes from everyone and the only time problems arise is when you edit the same lines and it can't deduce what should be done. But that doesn't usually happen that much. I'd say just keep on using SVN, but check *how* you're using it, since there's clearlysomething wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out git. Here are some links to get you started!

**Super Simple Getting Started Guide**
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

**Learn Git in 15 minutes by doing**
https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Git won't let you work in the same "instance" of a project, but it will allow you to merge your changes and see those changes before you merge. It will also allow you to go back to previous versions of your project.

Git knowledge and usage is par for the course in many places. My friend was only asked 1 question in his interview after his resume was looked over; he was asked if he knew how use git.

If you get a chance, make sure you read the git documentation on their website also.

EDIT: Git won't let you work on the same "instance" in terms of a live project where when he types on his side it auto syncs and updates your Toolbox.cpp on your side in real time. You can, however, work on the repository.